# experimentalDecorators vs @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators

Tags: reactjs, typescript, babeljs, decorator, typescript-decorator

Previously I don't had support of typescript in my react app. So I was using `@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators` plugin and the option `["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }]`.

Now I've added typescript support. And [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html) it is mentioned that I can use `experimentalDecorators` as a compiler option in my `.tsconfig` file.

Now I am confused. Do I've to add these things in both places? Or I can add support of decorators by using any one the above options.

Comment: Either or, don't use both. Personally since you already have babel as a traspiliation step, I'd only let typescript do type checking; use the babel plugin to do this transformation.

Comment: @CRice seems like when I add `experimentalDecorators` in `tsconfig` decorators aren't working. This made me think I've to add `@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators` anyhow in order to add support for decorators.

Comment: See [the docs here](https://github.com/babel/website/blob/master/docs/plugin-transform-typescript.md), in particular, item 4: *Changes to your tsconfig.json are not reflected in babel.* So it seems none of the tsconfig options will matter to babel, including `experimentalDecorators`. All transformations must be done with babel plugins.

Answer (score 1):

They both serve for the same purpose (enable decorators)

However, I would use babel plugin just because babel’s support is more generic and works with both JS and Typescript code.